# In the Poisson process $N,$ find $\operatorname E[2^{N(t)}e^{-\lambda t} \mid N(s) = k]$ and $\operatorname{Var}(N(t) \mid N(s) = k)$.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, poisson-process

> Consider the Poisson Process $\{N(t); t \geq 0\}$ with intensity $\lambda$. For $0 < s < t$, determine
>
> a) $\operatorname E[2^{N(t)}e^{-\lambda t} \mid N(s) = k]$ (Hint: $\operatorname E[e^{xN(t)}] = e^{-\lambda t(1-e^x)})$
>
> b) $\operatorname{Var}(N(t) \mid N(s) = k).$

This is what I've tried:

Edit: the last implication below was wrong. $\operatorname{E}[2^{N(t)}e^{-\lambda t}\mid N(s)=k]$ doesn't have to be equal to 1.

> a) First I calculated $\operatorname E[2^{N(t)}e^{-\lambda t}]{:}$
>
> \begin{align}
> & = e^{-\lambda t}E[2^{N(t)}] \\[10pt]
> & = e^{-\lambda t}E[e^{\ln(2)N(t)}] \\[10pt]
> & = e^{-\lambda t}e^{\lambda t} \text{ using the hint} \\[10pt]
> & = 1.
> \end{align}
>
> Then, using $\operatorname{E}[X] = \sum_{y} \operatorname{E}[X\mid Y=y]f_Y(y)$:
>
> $\operatorname{E}[2^{N(t)}e^{-\lambda t}] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \operatorname{E}[2^{N(t)}e^{-\lambda t}\mid N(s)=k]e^{-\lambda s}\frac{(\lambda s)^k}{k!}$
>
> $\implies 1 = e^{-\lambda s} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \operatorname{E}[2^{N(t)}e^{-\lambda t}\mid N(s)=k]\frac{(\lambda s)^k}{k!}$
>
> $\implies e^{\lambda s} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \operatorname{E}[2^{N(t)}e^{-\lambda t}\mid N(s)=k]\frac{(\lambda s)^k}{k!}$
>
> $\implies \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \operatorname{E}[2^{N(t)}e^{-\lambda t}\mid N(s)=k]$ should equal 1 because $e^{\lambda s} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\lambda s)^k}{k!}$.

On the second try I found $\operatorname{E}[2^{N(t)}e^{-\lambda t}\mid N(s)=k] = 2^k e^{-\lambda s}$ (thanks to Michael Hardy's answer):

\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[2^{N(t)}e^{-\lambda t}\mid N(s)=k] & = \operatorname{E}[2^{N(t) - N(s) + N(s)}e^{-\lambda t}\mid N(s)=k] \\[10pt]
& =e^{-\lambda t}\operatorname{E}[2^{N(t) - N(s)}\mid N(s)=k]\cdot\operatorname{E}[2^{N(s)}\mid N(s)=k] \\[10pt]
& =e^{-\lambda t}\operatorname{E}[2^{N(t-s)}]\cdot 2^k \\[10pt]
& =2^k e^{-\lambda t}e^{\lambda (t-s)}\\[10pt]
& =2^k e^{-\lambda s}.
\end{align}

Is this correct?

b) $\operatorname{Var}(N(t) \mid N(s) = k)$
\begin{align}
& = \operatorname{Var}(N(t) - N(s) + N(s) \mid N(s) = k) \\
& = \operatorname{Var}(N(t) - N(s) \mid N(s) = k) + \operatorname{Var}(N(s) \mid N(s) = k)\\
& = \operatorname{Var}(N(t) - N(s)) + 0\\
& = \lambda (t-s).
\end{align}

Could this be correct?

Any help or answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\v}{\operatorname{var}}$The number of arrivals in the time interval $[0,s]$ and the number of arrivals in the time interval $[s,t]$ are independent.

Therefore
\begin{align}
\v(N(t) \mid N(s)=k) & = \v(N(t)-k\mid N(s)=k) = \v(N(t)-N(s)\mid N(s)=k) \\[10pt]
& = \v(N(t) - N(s)) \text{ by the aforementioned independence} \\[10pt]
& = t-s \text{ since } N(t)-N(s) \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(t-s).
\end{align}

Similarly
\begin{align}
& \operatorname E(2^{N(t)} e^{-\lambda t}\mid N(s)=k) = \operatorname E(2^{(N(t) - N(s)) + k} e^{-\lambda t} \mid N(s)=k) = 2^k e^{-\lambda t} \operatorname E(2^{N(t) - N(s)}), 
\end{align}
and then use the hint.

Comment: Now it looks like you're saying that $N(t) = N(t) - N(s)$, but that doesn't seem logical, because there will surely be more arrivals in $[0,t]$ than in $[s,t]$, right? Also, $N(t) - N(s) \sim$ Poisson($\lambda (t-s)$).

Comment: Also, thank you for your edits. I somehow undid the first one because I didn't refresh before editing. Trying to fix it now.

Comment: I'm not saying $N(t) = N(t) - N(s).$ I'm saying $N(t)$ and $N(t) - N(s)$ both have the same conditional variance given the event $N(s) = k,$ because subtracting a constant from a random variable does not change the variance, and when one conditions on the event $N(s) = k$ then $N(s)$ is treated as a constant. $\qquad$

Comment: Ooh I understand now, thank you.